# CodeIgniter 3 with Capistrano htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, capistrano, codeigniter-3, capistrano3

I was using Capistrano to deploy my CI3 site and don't know much about rewrite rules. I was able to find htaccess rules from stackoverflow but none of them work for my case, so here I am.

I managed to have my home page running without any program, but none of the route works for me. They all return CI3 404 page not found error.

My Site Structure:

```
|-- .htaccess (under domain root)
|-- app/
    |-- current/ -> symlink to latest release folder
        |-- application/
        |-- public/
        |-- index.php
        |-- .htaccess (under project root)
        |-- ...other CI 3 folders and files
    |-- shared/
    |-- repo/
    |-- shared/
    |-- releases/
```

**.htaccess ( under domain root )**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^siteurl.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://siteurl.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect to CI3 root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/current/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/current/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess ( under project root )**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://siteurl.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['api/oauth'] = 'api/oauth';
```

So far, the welcome page works fine, but CI3 404 error page return for route api/oauth.

Please help!!! Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I just figure it out, it is a stupid mistake, the controller name is all cap, CI3 not able to understand it. Problem resolved. The .htaccess code works.